# Can't work with data from NSURLSession on main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I put network session code in viewDidLoad. And I configured session to be executed in main queue. In completion handler I save received data to class property.
Than after [dataTask resume] operation, I want to start processing and analyse this property, but from NSlog result I can see, that is empty.
So as I understand it's empty because block with processing network data is still being executed when I try to print my property, even though I configured session to main queue. What should I change to make it work properly?

Code:

```
@interface MainSourceDailyViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *allData;

@end

@implementation MainSourceDailyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]
                                                      delegate:nil
                                                 delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://xxxxxxxxxx"];

NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

    if ([[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread]){
        NSLog(@"In main thread--completion handler");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Not in main thread--completion handler");
    }
    self.allData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:array];
    NSLog(@"Answer in block: %@", self.allData);


}];
[dataTask resume];

NSLog(@"Final answer %@", self.allData);
```

}

Output:

```
2016-05-15 01:20:55.359  Final answer (null)
2016-05-15 01:20:56.500  In main thread--completion handler
2016-05-15 01:20:56.506  Answer in block: (
    {
Data contents
},
```

Comment: As soon as you get self.allData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:array]; you can post notification to all/one classes which need this data.

Answer (score 2):

Your configuration doesn't block the main thread, and you shouldn't try to. What it does is to call any delegate methods on the main thread.

Basically you need to embrace the fact that the process is asynchronous and deal with processing the data when it becomes available - I.e. In the completion block instead of after you start the task.

So basically it is already working properly, just not how you thought or want(ed).

Comment: Thank for your answer! Just want to clarify few things: 1) if it's only call delegates on main thread, why I can see in output that my completion handler is executed on main thread? I also tried to use session shared configuration and dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.allData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:array];
        }); and I got same result. 2) So I should put all my processing data stuff   inside my completion handler?

Comment: Completion is like a delegate. Put it there or call another method from there (often cleaner)